# PHPmailer sending to yahoo address

Tags: email, webforms, yahoo

I have set up the PHPmailer to have the To: and From: be the yahoo address (the $webem variable) and added a replyto address to be the actual user (the $FE variable).

I have also set up in yahoo an APP Password.

I tried sending both HTML and plain text emails from the form, but both get rejected.

PHPmailer setup:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';    // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = $webem;   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $epass;                   // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                    // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->From = $webem;
$mail->addAddress($webem);     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo($FE);
```

Response with SMTPDebug =2:

```
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.mail.yahoo.com ESMTP ready
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.new2youwheelrestoration.com
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp431.mail.gq1.yahoo.com Hello www.new2youwheelrestoration.com [73.27.216.5])
250-PIPELINING
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 41697280
250 AUTH PLAIN LOGIN XOAUTH2 OAUTHBEARER
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: cnVja21uMUB5YWhvby5jb20=
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: cnlua3Rma3l0dXB6Zm1jZA==
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<ruckmn1@yahoo.com>
2020-06-03 01:36:40 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Sender <ruckmn1@yahoo.com> OK
2020-06-03 01:36:40 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<ruckmn1@yahoo.com>
2020-06-03 01:36:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Recipient <ruckmn1@yahoo.com> OK
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
2020-06-03 01:36:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 Ok Send data ending with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Tue, 2 Jun 2020 21:36:39 -0400
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: ruckmn1@yahoo.com
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Root User <ruckmn1@yahoo.com>
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: patrick@patricklewis.net
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <4b835b094d049ffccbdf32174e9b7a48@www.new2youwheelrestoration.com>
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Priority: 3
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.8 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/)
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: testing web form
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Patrick
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: patrick@patricklewis.net
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13;
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER:
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: .
2020-06-03 01:36:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable
2020-06-03 01:36:41 SMTP ERROR: DATA END command failed: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable
SMTP Error: data not accepted.
2020-06-03 01:36:41 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-06-03 01:36:41 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 Service Closing transmission
```

How do I resolve the Mailbox unavailable/data not accepted error?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get this to work is to remove the replyto address.

I set the from email to the yahoo account that I logged into and the to address to another yahoo account that my client uses.